# The Posted content type isn't multipart/form data IO exception

Tags: java, jsp, post, weblogic

i would like to asks some questions, recently i had to migrate our legacy application to weblogic, but some feature can't be used (multipart post form), here is my code:

noticeWrite.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>

<%@ page import="common.Util"%>

<%@ page import="common.Const"%>

<%

String lang_cls=Util.nullChk(request.getParameter("lang_cls"),"eng");

String sectn_nm=Util.nullChk(request.getParameter("sectn_nm"),"notice");

System.out.println("request.getContentType() ====> " + request.getContentType());

%>

<jsp:include flush="true" page="/admin/include/top_brd.jsp" />

<jsp:include flush="true" page="/admin/include/board_left.jsp" />



<form name="frm" method="post" action="noticeProc.jsp" onsubmit="return frmSubmit(this)">

    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="insert">

    <input type="hidden" name="lang_cls" value="<%=lang_cls%>">

    <input type="hidden" name="sectn_nm" value="<%=sectn_nm%>">

    <input type="hidden" name="board_seq" value="">

<!--right start-->

<div id="subRight">

<h3><%=Const.getConstant(sectn_nm)%>

<p class="homeNevi"><img src="../.././common/home_imgs/neviHome.gif"

    alt="Home" />  <span></span>  Administrator  <span>></span> 

Data & Informasi  <span>></span>  <%=Const.getConstant(sectn_nm)%>

</p>

</h3>





<!--edit start-->

<div class="bleStyle_border">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" frame="void" border="1px"

    bordercolor="#b1a587" class="homeList">

    <caption> </caption>

    <colgroup>

        <col style="width: 80px;" />

        <col style="" />

        <col style="width: 80px;" />

        <col style="width: 260px;" />

    </colgroup>

    <tr>

        <th scope="row">* Judul</th>

        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="board_titl"

            msg="Please type a title" maxlength="100" class="iput_txt"

            style="width: 99%;" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <th scope="row">* Penulis</th>

        <td><input type="text" name="make_nm" msg="Please type a writer"

            maxlength="20" value="${sess_mbr_id}" class="iput_txt"

            style="width: 97%;" /></td>

        <th scope="row">File</th>

        <td class="bleLeft"><input type="file" name="file_1"

            class="iput_file" onkeypress="blur()" /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td colspan="4"><textarea cols="" rows="" name="board_cntt"

            msg="Please type a content" maxlength="5000" class="bleText_area"

            style="width: 98%; height: 100px;"></textarea>

            <script language="JavaScript1.2">

                editor_generate('board_cntt');

            </script>   

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

</div>



<div class="bleBtn_box"><!--future extention of buttons is considered. so, buttons without class is orderly backward. be cautious!-->

<a href="javascript:goToPage('noticeList.jsp','')"><img

    src="../.././common/home_imgs/daftar_btn.gif" alt="" /></a><!--daftar_btn button-->

<input type="image" src="../.././common/home_imgs/kirim_btn.gif" alt=""

    class="btnLeft" /><!--kirim_btn button--></div>

</div>

<!--right start-->

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

<!--

function frmSubmit(form){

    form.encoding = "multipart/form-data";

    return chkNull(form);

}

//-->

</script>

<jsp:include flush="true" page="/admin/include/board_bottom.jsp" />
```

noticeProc.jsp

```
<%@ page import="board.NoticeBoardMng"%>

<%@ page import="entity.Board"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="common.Util,

                com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest,

                com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.DefaultFileRenamePolicy"%>

<%

request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");



String savePath= Util.getMessage("filepath","NOTICE_FILE_PATH");

//System.out.println("savePath =====> " + savePath);

int sizeLimit=5*1024*1024;

//MultipartRequest multi=new MultipartRequest(request,savePath,sizeLimit,"UTF-8",new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());

MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request,savePath,sizeLimit,"UTF-8");



String mode       = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("mode"));

String board_seq  = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("board_seq"));

String lang_cls   = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("lang_cls"));

String sectn_nm   = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("sectn_nm"));

String make_nm    = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("make_nm"));

String board_titl = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("board_titl"));

String board_cntt = multi.getParameter("board_cntt");

String file_1     = Util.nullChk(multi.getFilesystemName("file_1"));

String sfield     = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("sfield"));

String sword      = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("sword"));

String nowPage    = Util.nullChk(multi.getParameter("nowPage"));



//board_cntt=Util.transHtml(board_cntt);



Board board=new Board();

board.setBoard_seq(board_seq);

board.setLang_cls(lang_cls);

board.setSectn_nm(sectn_nm);

board.setMake_nm(make_nm);

board.setBoard_titl(board_titl);

board.setBoard_cntt(board_cntt);

board.setBoard_cntt_long(board_cntt);



if(file_1 == null){

    board.setFile_1("");

}else{

    board.setFile_1(file_1);

}

%>

<html>

<head>

<script language="javascript" src="/common/js/common.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="frm" method="post" action="">

<input type="hidden" name="lang_cls" value="<%=lang_cls%>">

<input type="hidden" name="sectn_nm" value="<%=sectn_nm%>">

<input type="hidden" name="board_seq" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="sfield" value="<%=sfield%>">

<input type="hidden" name="sword" value="<%=sword%>">

<input type="hidden" name="nowpage" value="<%=nowPage%>">

</form>

<%

boolean isSuccess=false;

NoticeBoardMng bMng=new NoticeBoardMng();



if("insert".equals(mode)){

    isSuccess=bMng.saveBoard(board);

    if(isSuccess){

        out.println("<script language='javascript'>");

        out.println("goToPage('noticeList.jsp','"+board_seq+"')");

        out.println("</script>");

    }else{

        out.println("<script language='javascript'>");

        out.println("alert('fail!');");

        out.println("history.back();");

        out.println("</script>");

    }   

}else if("update".equals(mode)){

    isSuccess=bMng.updateBoard(board);

    if(isSuccess){

        out.println("<script language='javascript'>");

        out.println("goToPage('noticeList.jsp','')");

        out.println("</script>");

    }

}

%>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is, when i clicked submit button, file is stored to server but text field and text area value didn't stored to database and throws an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn&#39;t multipart/form-data

    at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:130)

    at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:94)

    at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:219)

    at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:170)

    at jsp_servlet._admin._board.__noticeproc._jspService(__noticeproc.java:109)

    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:185)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)

    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)

    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)

    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I need your advice, what's wrong with this? because it works fine on tomcat, but cannot run under weblogic, thank you.

edit:

from the error log, it says error on __noticeproc.java:109, here are the content:

> String savePath= Util.getMessage("filepath","NOTICE_FILE_PATH");
>   //System.out.println("savePath =====> " + savePath); int
>   sizeLimit=5*1024*1024; //MultipartRequest multi=new
>   MultipartRequest(request,savePath,sizeLimit,"UTF-8",new
>   DefaultFileRenamePolicy()); **MultipartRequest multi = new
>   MultipartRequest(request,savePath,sizeLimit,"UTF-8")**;

here is the parameter from firebug:

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------------2572913021633
>   Content-Length: 1092
>
> -----------------------------2572913021633
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mode"
>
> insert
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lang_cls"
>
> eng
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sectn_nm"
>
> office3
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="board_seq"
>
> -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="board_titl"
>
> TestPage
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="make_nm"
>
> agit
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_1"; filename="" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="board_cntt"
>
> testpage
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x"
>
> 57
>   -----------------------------2572913021633 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="y"
>
> 5
>   -----------------------------2572913021633--

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this attribute in the form tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and remove from the submit function that you are setting manually.

Comment: What browser are you using? Try to see in the Chrome Developer tools or firefox firebug how is the request going, or print and put here.

Comment: the comment is too long for the parameter sent by firefox to put it here, i will post as my question above

Comment: @galih, looks like its being sent all the data and somehow your MultipartRequest is not recognizing it, try to handle the request with Apache Commons Upload, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: there is nothing wrong with file uploading, because file successfully uploaded to server as expected, but the value from the text field and text area can't be stored to database... FYI i'm using ibatis for CRUD in this webapp

Comment: Looks like there is a problem, because the exception is in the line that do the upload, check if the files on server are not empty

Comment: The database code isn't being executed because there are errors in the upload

Comment: i've checked the file in the server are not empty, and the content is suitable to my local laptop. So file successfully uploaded but query isn't executed because of IO exception right?

Comment: Yeah, but the class that do the upload is throwing the exception, maybe there is a problem with this implementation, give a try on the commons upload, just to check

Comment: one question, if i use common upload jar, do i have to remove cos.jar?

Comment: I guess you doesn't need to remove